# The stack of a lua coroutine is entered implicitly without a call to resume?

Tags: error-handling, lua, callstack, implicit, coroutine

I am using lua coroutines (lua 5.1) to create a plugin system for an application.  I was hoping to use coroutines so that the plugin could operate as if it were a separate application program which yields once per processing frame.  The plugin programs generally follow a formula something like:

```
function Program(P)
    -- setup --
    NewDrawer(function()
        -- this gets rendered in a window for this plugin program --
        drawstuff(howeveryouwant)
    end)
    -- loop --
    local continue = true
    while continue do
        -- frame by frame stuff excluding rendering (handled by NewDrawer) --
        P = coroutine.yield()
    end
end
```

Each plugin is resumed in the main loop of the application once per frame.  Then when drawing begins each plugin has an individual window it draws in which is when the function passed to NewDrawer is executed.

Something like this:

```
while MainContinue do
    -- other stuff left out --
    ExecutePluginFrames() -- all plugin coroutines resumed once

    BeginRendering()
    -- other stuff left out --
    RenderPluginWindows() -- functions passed to NewDrawer called.
    EndRendering()
end
```

However I found that this suddenly began acting strangely and messing up my otherwise robust error handling system whenever an error occurred in the rendering.  It took me a little while to wrap my head around what was happening but it seems that the call to WIN:Draw() which I expected to be in the main thread's call stack (because it is handled by the main application) was actually causing an implicit jump into the coroutine's call stack.

At first the issue was that the program was closing suddenly with no useful error output.  Then after looking at a stack traceback of the rendering function defined in the plugin program I saw that everything leading up to the window's Draw from the main thread was not there and that yield was in the call stack.

It seems that because the window was created in the thread and the drawing function, that they are being handled by that thread's call stack, which is a problem because it means they are outside of the pcall set up in the main thread.

Is this suppose to happen? is it the result of a bug/shortcut in the C source? am I doing something wrong or at least not correctly enough? is there a way to handle this cleanly?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question since you are not showing how you call/resume `Program`. Can you simplify your code to show interactions with the rest of your application?

Comment: Added edits, its in RenderPluginWindows() where the implicit change in call stack appears to be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered why this was happening in my case.  The render objects which called the function passed to NewDrawer are initialized on creation (by the c code) with a pointer to the lua state that created them and this is used for accessing their associated lua data and for calling the draw function.  I had not seen the connection between lua_State and coroutines.  So as it turns out it is possible for functions to be called in the stack after yield if C code is causing them.

As far as a solution goes I've decided to break the program into two coroutines, one for rendering and one for processing.  This fixes the problem by allowing the creating thread of the render objects to also be the calling thread, and keeps the neat advantages of the independence of the rendering loop and processing loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the effect you are describing. This is the code I'm running:

```
local drawer = {}
function NewDrawer(func)
  table.insert(drawer, func)
end

function Program(P)
    NewDrawer(function()
        print("inside program", P)
    end)
    -- loop --
    local continue = true
    while continue do
        -- frame by frame stuff excluding rendering (handled by NewDrawer) --
        P = coroutine.yield()
    end
end

local coro = coroutine.create(Program)
local MainContinue = true
while MainContinue do
    -- other stuff left out --
    -- ExecutePluginFrames() -- all plugin coroutines resumed once
    coroutine.resume(coro, math.random(10))
    -- RenderPluginWindows() -- functions passed to NewDrawer called.
    for _, plugin in ipairs(drawer) do
      plugin()
    end
    MainContinue = false
end
```

When I step through the code and look at the stack, the callback that is set in NewDrawer is called in the "main" thread as it should. You can see it yourself if you call `coroutine.running()` which returns the current thread or `nil` if you are inside the main thread.

Comment: Hmm well that is behaving as expected.  Well I didn't expect these things to make a difference but here are some other possible causes:
The plugin is executed in a different environment.  The call to the drawing functions passed to NewDrawer is made in a C function.
And the C function passes a full userdata to the function it calls which is created inside the plugin program.

Comment: Since you can't share your code for others to execute, I think you need to resort to adding `print` statements around your resume/yield commands as well as calls to `coroutine.running()` to figure out where the switch you see happens. I work with coroutines on a regular basis (using them for [debugging and live coding](http://studio.zerobrane.com)), but have never seen the situation you are describing.